# How to find entry that is between two dates?

Tags: sql, presto

I have a table as:

```
Id start_timestamp end_timestamp
1 2021-07-12 03:00:00   2021-07-13 11:58:05 
2 2021-07-13 04:00:00 2021-07-13 05:00:00
3 2021-07-13 04:00:00 2021-07-13 09:00:00
4 2021-07-13 04:00:00 NULL
5 2020-04-10 04:00:00 2020-04-10 04:01:00
```

....

I want to find all records that fall between two specific timestamps? Basically I'm looking to understand what process ran during a high pick time of the day (it doesn't matter if they have 1 sec in the window or hours.. just occurrence in the window is enough)

So if the timestamps are `2021-07-13 00:00:00` to `2021-07-13 04:30:00`
The query will return

```
1
2
3
4
```

How can I do that with SQL? (Preferably Presto)

Answer (score 1):

This is the overlapping range problem.  You may use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    (end_timestamp > '2021-07-13 00:00:00' OR end_timestamp IS NULL) AND
    (start_timestamp < '2021-07-13 04:30:00' OR start_timestamp IS NULL);
```

My answer assumes that a missing start/end timestamp value in the table logically means that this value should not be considered.  This seems to be the logic you want here.

Comment: But this will also give me records that started on 2021-07-14 0:00:00 which are out of range

Comment: To clarify, do you want to detect _overlap_ of your custom range, or do you want to detect if the custom range be completely contained within the two timestamps in the table?  If you want the _former_ (which is what your sample data seems to say), then my answer is already correct.

Comment: as long as record is in the range it's enough (it doesn't matter what is the duration in the range). To clarify if the log end_timestamp is 2021-07-12 03:00:01 and the query start_timestamp is 2021-07-12 03:00:00 - The record should be shown in the result